# Have one text element track the position of another text element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I would like to have the red "Aliquam" text inside of the div with class ".absolute" track on top of the exact position of the (blue) "Aliquam" text inside ".aliquam-span", including on browser resize.

I've tried a few different ways to do this but haven't had much luck - hoping that someone here can help.

Nesting the text as a child of the span is not an option, unfortunately.

Thank you!

```js
let aliquam = document.querySelector('.aliquam-span')
let aliquamAbsolute = document.querySelector('.red-text')

let aliquamRect = aliquam.getBoundingClientRect()
let aliquamAbsoluteRect = aliquamAbsolute.getBoundingClientRect()

let xOffset = aliquamRect.left - aliquamAbsoluteRect.left
let yOffset = aliquamRect.top - aliquamAbsoluteRect.top

console.log({xOffset})

aliquamAbsolute.style.left = `${xOffset}px`
aliquamAbsolute.style.top = `${yOffset}px`
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0; 
}

.red-text {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  left: '200px';
}

.aliquam-span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Maecenas a finibus sapien. Duis pulvinar ligula vel arcu cursus, in euismod nunc iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce facilisis quis libero nec bibendum. Donec suscipit eros sit amet ex condimentum ullamcorper. Aliquam dictum, risus id pharetra congue, nisl nisi facilisis enim, sit amet facilisis nunc diam condimentum eros. Aenean euismod turpis id enim commodo sagittis. <span class="aliquam-span">Aliquam</span> eget dolor eget nulla tempus imperdiet. Praesent gravida, nisl quis malesuada faucibus, orci purus ultrices velit, ut porttitor libero ante at nisl. Duis eget convallis risus. Nunc vitae orci non tellus ultricies vestibulum in a augue. Vestibulum hendrerit leo ac nunc rutrum imperdiet. Integer sem tellus, maximus vel interdum ut, accumsan vel orci. Mauris maximus leo vitae felis dapibus euismod. Nulla facilisi. Donec ac ullamcorper justo.</p>
    <div class="absolute">
      <p class="red-text">Aliquam</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: you want `red` to follow `blue`? but for what and how will `red` have to change?

Comment: I want the red text to have the exact same position as the blue text. It should overlay on top so that the blue text is behind it. It's for an animation but I need to set the text to track first. This is a minimal example of something a bit more involved.

Comment: why don't you wait until the effect starts to add `red`? add `red` at the beginning we need to use `IntersectionObserver` to keep track of `blue`

Comment: Wrapping the textnode in an element would resolve the task in the most clean way. Is there a good reason to not to use it?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the text effect seen on the second section of this website: https://www.epic.net/

I've got everything working except for when user resizes the window. I inspected what they are doing and this is the HTML setup they have. I also tried nesting the element but then I cannot achieve the animation effect.

Comment: If you mean "About" part, every single word in it is wrapped within `<div class="word">`.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me, try it:

```js
function changePosition () {
   let aliquam = document.querySelector('.aliquam-span');
   let aliquamAbsolute = document.querySelector('.red-text').parentElement;
   let aliquamRect = aliquam.getBoundingClientRect();
        
   aliquamAbsolute.style.top = aliquamRect.top + 'px';
   aliquamAbsolute.style.right = aliquamRect.right + 'px';
   aliquamAbsolute.style.left = aliquamRect.left + 'px';
   aliquamAbsolute.style.bottom = aliquamRect.bottom + 'px';

}
window.onresize = changePosition;
window.onload = changePosition;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.wrap {
  
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0; 
}

.red-text {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  left: '200px';
  margin: 0;
}

.aliquam-span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Maecenas a finibus sapien. Duis pulvinar ligula vel arcu cursus, in euismod nunc iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce facilisis quis libero nec bibendum. Donec suscipit eros sit amet ex condimentum ullamcorper. Aliquam dictum, risus id pharetra congue, nisl nisi facilisis enim, sit amet facilisis nunc diam condimentum eros. Aenean euismod turpis id enim commodo sagittis. <span class="aliquam-span">Aliquam</span> eget dolor eget nulla tempus imperdiet. Praesent gravida, nisl quis malesuada faucibus, orci purus ultrices velit, ut porttitor libero ante at nisl. Duis eget convallis risus. Nunc vitae orci non tellus ultricies vestibulum in a augue. Vestibulum hendrerit leo ac nunc rutrum imperdiet. Integer sem tellus, maximus vel interdum ut, accumsan vel orci. Mauris maximus leo vitae felis dapibus euismod. Nulla facilisi. Donec ac ullamcorper justo.</p>
    <div class="absolute">
      <p class="red-text">Aliquam</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hoang - My use case is constrained in that I cannot edit the properties of the parent, need to translate position of ".red-text" directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should target the `div` that is being set as the absolutely positioned one. So select `.absolute` instead of the `.red-text`.

```js
let aliquam = document.querySelector('.aliquam-span')
let aliquamAbsolute = document.querySelector('.absolute')

let aliquamRect = aliquam.getBoundingClientRect()
let aliquamAbsoluteRect = aliquamAbsolute.getBoundingClientRect()

let xOffset = aliquamRect.left - aliquamAbsoluteRect.left

let yOffset = aliquamRect.top - aliquamAbsoluteRect.top

console.log({xOffset, yOffset})

aliquamAbsolute.style.left = `${xOffset}px`
aliquamAbsolute.style.top = `${yOffset}px`
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  inset: 0;
}

.red-text {
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.aliquam-span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Maecenas a finibus sapien. Duis pulvinar ligula vel arcu cursus, in euismod nunc iaculis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce facilisis quis libero nec bibendum. Donec suscipit eros sit amet ex condimentum ullamcorper. Aliquam dictum, risus id pharetra congue, nisl nisi facilisis enim, sit amet facilisis nunc diam condimentum eros. Aenean euismod turpis id enim commodo sagittis. <span class="aliquam-span">Aliquam</span> eget dolor eget nulla tempus imperdiet. Praesent gravida, nisl quis malesuada faucibus, orci purus ultrices velit, ut porttitor libero ante at nisl. Duis eget convallis risus. Nunc vitae orci non tellus ultricies vestibulum in a augue. Vestibulum hendrerit leo ac nunc rutrum imperdiet. Integer sem tellus, maximus vel interdum ut, accumsan vel orci. Mauris maximus leo vitae felis dapibus euismod. Nulla facilisi. Donec ac ullamcorper justo.</p>
    <div class="absolute">
      <p class="red-text">Aliquam</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful but doesn't work for my use case. I need to position the .red-text element. I changed the code snippet for that it's position relative now and lets me access top and left properties. Also, it works in the mini snippet but when I expand to full screen the position is off :(.

Comment: Copepen example: https://codepen.io/learyjk/pen/RwBzexQ?editors=1111

Comment: @learyjk the reason it doesn't work when you expand to full page is probably because the code is being run only once (in the mini snippet window), so as you've done in the codepen, if you add a resize event listener, it will probably work? Let me look into the other parts you mentioned.

Comment: @learyjk looks like the codepen example achieves what you wanted to do. Is there something still wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks @cSharp - I really appreciate you looking into it. The Codepen is ALMOST there but there are jitters on resize and sometimes it jsut doesn't work altogether. I tried to debounce it but still no joy :(.

Comment: @learyjk looks like it doesn't work when you resize the window, but let go of the mouse a little bit after. You could try [throttling and debouncing](https://web.archive.org/web/20220714020647/https://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html) it. But I think looking for another method of getting this done will be more reliable, or just being okay with animation not working perfectly while the window is being resized.

Answer (score 0):

The folks at GSAP helped me out on this one!

Three different answers here:

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/35705-tracking-position-of-a-text-span-with-javascript/